# Как получить максимальный индекс в элементе listBox?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, есть у элемента listBox такое свойство SelectedIndex. К примеру, у меня в элементе 4 items, но это значение может меняться и я не буду знать, какое их число, при срабатывании таймера идет код

```
listBox1.SelectedItem++;
```

И когда это значение достигло максимума (в нашем случае 4), сделать такой код

```
listBox1.SelectedItem = 0;
```

Я не понимаю, как получить максимальный индекс, я пробовал listBox1.Items.Count, но у Индексов идёт отсчет от 0, а не от 1.

Comment: Тут просто надо логику включить, которой у вас, как видно, нет...

Comment: Наверное просто уже поздно и мозг устал за весь день, в такое время лучше не писать код, а то он будет очень кривым.

Comment: Спасибо, посмеялся от души)

Comment: откуда у вас такой рейтинг, при такой сображалке)

Answer (score 1):

listBox1.Items.Count - 1, не?

---

[ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx)

> С помощью этого свойства можно получить ссылку на список элементов, хранящихся в настоящее время в объекте ListBox.